# Why is my yarn install / yarn add extremely slow?

Tags: performance, vue.js, electron, yarnpkg, electron-builder

[Terminal output showing how long my yarn install is taking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGQ8I.png)

I'm making an electron / vue desktop app, and using yarn to manage dependencies. Since I added firebase and firebase-tools as dependencies, yarn install is now unbelievably slow. I'm not sure if I should just ignore the postinstall script which is (electron-builder install-app-deps) or if I need it. Any advice on what to do here would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably because there is a lot of data for your CPU to crunch through

Comment: @GBWDev Are you sure? This just started happening basically right after I added those two dependencies. Does it make it that much slower? it's like multiple minutes now. And I have like a 2019 Macbook pro...